# Read Text File Pipe to Pipe Separated File in Bash Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a data file containing text. I am wondering what might the best method in Bash to read that file and pipe the output out to newly created Pipe Separated File? The delimiters are tricky here for me...

The file in question can have either one or multiple text data fields as such:

```
First Name: Bill Last Name: Gates
Color: Blue
Start: 12/11/19 End:12/12/20
```

And so the Pipe Separated File should read like so:

```
Bill|Gates|Blue|12/11/19|12/12/20
```

I am having trouble with the parsing mechanism in my script. I've been previously using this sed example which would replace `,` and remove `""` in CSV files. I am looking to modify.

```
sed -e 's/","/|/g' -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' $file
```

Assuming each variable that needs to be pipe separated is preceded by an ":" and we know the word before the next variable that needs to be separated, what might be the best method? Is sed even the way? I am worried about instances where the last word in the data might be a label name.

```
ie. First Name: Last Last Name:
```

It should have the same input always, albeit it could be slightly more complicated. Nevertheless, it should be standard labels affixing the data fields always.

Edit: I understand. I don't have any particular base data to suggest. It's more open-ended.  I suppose im simply looking to simply convert to PSV file based on text file with labels which are always the same.

The data to separate should always come after :

I don't have a full set of the words that would be labeling the data as that would be very lengthy. Let's assume the simple example above.

Edit via selected answer:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk  '
BEGIN{
  FS="[: ]"
  OFS="|"
}
match($0,/First.*Last Name: /){
  first_name=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/First Name: |Last.*/,"",first_name)
  last_name=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  next
}
match($0,/^Color:/){
  color=$NF
  next
}
match($0,/Start.*End:/){
  start=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/Start: | End:/,"",start)
  end=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  print first_name,last_name,color,start,end
}
'  data.txt > data_pipe_separated.txt
```

Outputs:

```
Bill |Gates|Blue|12/11/19|12/12/20
```

Comment: Could you please confirm if your Input_file looks like shown sample always? Or its different from shown sample?

Comment: Please input example with multiple records. Not clear what the requirements are

Comment: How do you know which line is the start of a new entry, and which is the finish?  Or is there only one person per file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following (tested and written in provided samples).

```
awk  '
BEGIN{
  FS="[: ]"
  OFS="|"
}
match($0,/First.*Last Name: /){
  first_name=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/First Name: | Last.*/,"",first_name)
  last_name=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  next
}
match($0,/^Color:/){
  color=$NF
  next
}
match($0,/Start.*End:/){
  start=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/Start: | End:/,"",start)
  end=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  print first_name,last_name,color,start,end
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:***  Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk  '                                             ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                                             ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  FS="[: ]"                                        ##Setting FS as space OR : here.
  OFS="|"                                          ##Setting OFS as |(pipe) here.
}                                                  ##Closing BEGIN section of this program here.
match($0,/First.*Last Name: /){                    ##Using match condition to match a regex First to till string Last Name: here in a line.
  first_name=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)             ##Creating variable first_name whose value is sub string of RSTART to RLENGTH values.
  gsub(/First Name: |Last.*/,"",first_name)        ##Globally substituting either First Name: OR Last.* with NULL in variable first_name.
  last_name=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)              ##Creating variable last_name whose value is sub string of RSTART+RLENGTH value to till end of line value.
  next                                             ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}                                                  ##Closing BLOCK for above condition here.
match($0,/^Color:/){                               ##Using match to match regex from string Color: then do following.
  color=$NF                                        ##Creating variable named color whose value is last field of current line.
  next                                             ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}                                                  ##Closing BLOCK for above condition here.
match($0,/Start.*End:/){                           ##Using match to match regex Start.*End: here in current line, if match found then do following.
  start=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)                  ##Creating variable start whose value is sub string of RSTART to RLENGTH here.
  gsub(/Start: | End:/,"",start)                   ##Globally substituting Start: OR End: with NULL in variable start here.
  end=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)                    ##Creating variable end whose value is sub string of RSTART+RLENGTH till end of the line here.
  print first_name,last_name,color,start,end       ##Printing variables named first_name,last_name,color,start,end here.
}                                                  ##Closing BLOCK for above condition here.
' Input_file                                       ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: This does indeed work. It pumps out an extra space after the first data set but no biggie :) This works just fine. Thank you for understanding. This should give me enough to meld if the labels change or give me grounds for a better question going forward.

Comment: @CameronA, Glad that it helped you, fixed the space issue in Name now, cheers.

Comment: The conventional, idiomatic `awk` way of writing the condition `match($0,/First.*Last Name: /)` is simply `/First.*Last Name: /`, and similarly for the other two conditions,

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Sir, why I have used specifically `match` because I used variables `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` later on-wards which will be SET once we use match, kindly do lemme know if missed something here, I will edit my answer then.

Comment: OK — it seems to be necessary to use `match()` then.  At least with the macOS (BSD) version of `awk`, using `match` explicitly is necessary.  It is still true that it is normal to use a simple regex; it might be worth noting why you have to use `match()`, or you could let these comments do the job for you.  Your choice.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I added detailed manner explanation in my post too now for better understanding sir.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
$ sed -nz 's/[^:]*: *\(\S*\)/\1|/gp;s/\n//'  input_file
Bill|Gates|Blue|12/11/19|12/12/20|
```

the pattern `/[^:]*: *\(\S*\)/` searches for zero or more non-colons, `[^:]*`, followed by a colon and zero or more spaces, `: *`, followed by zero or more non-space characters `\(\S*\)`. The replacement is `\1|` which are the contents of the captured group followed by a pipe character. Then `s/\n//` removes new lines.